# HTML relative centre align

Tags: html, css, center, alignment

I'm trying to centre align an image using a div and a CSS class (the  tag is wrapped in a div class="center" tag). What I'm using at the moment is working in Dreamweaver (when I go to design view) but not when I load the page up in Safari. Here is my code:

```
.center {
  display:inline; 
  text-align:center; 
  -webkit-inline; 
  -webkit-center; 
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Sorry for asking such a simple question, I'm completely new to HTML, my experience is in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `text-align:center;` to it's `.center` parent DIV. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
 text-align:center;
}

.center {
 display:inline;
 background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you. HTML has all of these little caveats which take a while to get used to!

Comment: It won't let me do it for another 4 minutes, I'll also upvote the guy when I get to 15 rep.

Answer (score 5):

`text-align: center` caused the content to be centered (within the container), and not the container itself being centered.

Since you use `display: inline`, the size of the container will be the same as its content, and the centering will not have the effect you're after.

Either, you use the `margin: 0 auto` to center the container (towards its parent container), OR you change `display: inline` to `display: block`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use margin : 0 auto , to a vertical align , but if you want a vertical-horizontal align , you need a code like this:

```
.center{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-200px;
position:absolute;
top :50%;
left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

margin: 0 auto. Is what you're looking for. You'll need a width also.

div.center { margin:0 auto; width: 20%;background:orange;}

Comment: Surely that would invoke absolute positioning?

Comment: No, this is unrelated. Absolute positioning is about removing an element from the flow and being able to position wherever we want on the page without any interaction with the rest of the flow (the rest of content). Useful when you want to superimpose content, mess up a webpage and so on ;) Try to avoid absolute positioning if you're a beginner.